# He prefers hot weather like.... "in the south - Why are there two prepositions?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I just joined after a few years of coming to your boards for advice as I need help with a specific sentence.

"He likes warm weather LIKE IN SPAIN / LIKE IN THE SOUTH"

Is "Like" being used here as a preposition? If so, how is the prep "in" being used? I can see it is forming a noun but can't explain it.

Thanks! I am looking forward to being an active member of the site.

Comment: This is a very informal usage. What is implied is "...like [the weather they have] in Spain".

Comment: It's a preposition with the preposition phrase "in Spain/ in the south" as its complement. Here, "like" is in competition with "as", which is preferred in formal style. Some would say that the complement of "like" should be analysed as a reduced clause, cf. "like it is in Spain".

Comment: Great! Thank you both. Makes perfect sense. This site is amazing!!!

Comment: @BillJ Please make that an answer; comments can disappear over time, and you don’t get as much rep for upvotes.